# Проблема с отображением img на сайте в Android WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Проблема с отображением сайта в Android WebView. Те img в src которых адрес на Google Drive (например https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1wNSgg8UB-QLtvejFzsNXcD.. ) иногда не подгружаются (виден alt). Это происходит спустя какое-то время после открытия приложения и перехода по нескольким внутренним ссылкам сайта. После того как делаешь перерыв и открываешь приложение заново - с картинками снова все впорядке. Потом все повторяется.

При этом:

• Это происходит только с картинками с сылками на Google Диск. C картинками по всем другим адресам все нормально.

• Это происходит только в WebView. В браузере эти картинки на сайте отображаются.

Не понимаю, в чем дело:

• Лимит на кол-во запросов к Google Диску в единицу времени? Не нашел такого. Да и в браузере проблема отсутствует.

• WebView плохо отрабатывает медленный респонз с Google Диска? (А это визуально так. Изображения с него подгружаются визуально медленнее остольных). Но после перезапуска приложения какое-то время все в порядке.

[image: Printscreen]